# CoreImage, iOS5 and speed, why is CoreImage so slow?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, core-graphics, core-image

I'm finally sitting down to convert some of our graphics libraries to use CoreImage to render images (for things like blending two images) and I've got it working but its slow (iOS5.01 iPhone 4S).  I thought the promise of CoreImage was hardware acceleration, here is what I'm doing:

```
        CIImage *intputBackgroundImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:backgroundImageRef];
    CIImage *inputImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:inputImageRef];

    CIFilter *multiply = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIMultiplyBlendMode"];
    [multiply setDefaults];

    [multiply setValue:intputBackgroundImage forKey:@"inputBackgroundImage"];
    [multiply setValue:inputImage forKey:@"inputImage"];

    CIImage *result = multiply.outputImage;
    CIContext *ctx = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];

    CGImageRef resultRef = [ctx createCGImage:result fromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, imgFrame.size.width, imgFrame.size.height)];
    UIImage *resultImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:resultRef];
    CGImageRelease(resultRef);
```

It works, I get an image which has the inputImage blended into the backgroundImage but it actually takes longer than if I had just done it using CoreGraphics and a CGContext().  Is there a way to check if this work isn't being done on the GPU, is there a reason it wouldn't be?

Thanks,

Comment: What did you find when you profiled this code in Instruments?

Comment: I'll try that @PeterHosey.  After reading around some more I'm starting to suspect its because I'm going in and out of GPU/VRAM.  ie, the data gets copied to GPU/VRAM, work is done, its copied back to RAM (UIImage) then copied back to VRAM (display UIImage).

Comment: @Shizam - Uploading to the GPU is pretty fast, and even a `glReadPixels()` call to pull information back from the GPU can be done in 10 ms or so for a decent sized image on the iPhone 4. This certainly can be done far faster on the GPU than CPU, so there has to be some hidden overhead somewhere in there.  Perhaps theres a format conversion being done on the CPU somewhere within Core Image (possibly to and from a CGImageRef). As Peter suggests, Time Profiler might suss out where the bottleneck is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things that you need rerender are best for ci, or things that need to do multiple filters.

It's currently slower because the items have to be copied from cpu memory to gpu memory (no opengl unified memory support on ios).

This means that since you are only doing one effect, it will take more time due to the double copy.

Comment: I think this is the gist of my problem and I'll need to figure out how to use 'CAEAGLLayers'.